# Sorting and Filtering on the client side. How should approach this?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

GraphQL API from backend provides tabulated information of about 10000+ items (normalized data) (ie contact info: name, title, company, phone number, email...)

Upon receiving this data in the front end. I want to sort by fields and search and filter by keywords.

The approach I am thinking is, once the data is received via graphQL API to the component I can trigger onclick event to call a function to sort etc. within the component.

Is this a naive approach? Would there be better method to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle sorting I guess should be to handle it on server-side. If you really want to do it on client-side, you should first show data as they are and then trigger `onChage` when user change sorting or keyword.

I would recommend you to use `lodash` library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash for sorting and filtering.

Here are some useful link that will tell you more about server-side and client-side sorting.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/difference-between-client-side-paging-and-server-side-paging

[Pagination: Server Side or Client Side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407878/pagination-server-side-or-client-side)

[Where data sort should be done ? Server or client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721430/where-data-sort-should-be-done-server-or-client)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/249897/web-app-filtering-information-client-side-vs-server-side

Comment: If concurrent user is like 50 people and they are requesting sort and filter to the backend, wouldn't this overload server side, making it slow?

Comment: @LeeDongyobEric well 50 requests are literally nothing. You should make your server handle more requests. When you have a lot of data (like more than a million and it will get that big very soon), you should always make requests to server-side and filter and sort them in your database (remember to use pagination, since it would be much quicker because you're sending only 20-30 records)

Comment: Question: You are sending 20-30 records but you are also sorting millions of data, wouldn't this make server sluggish when you have millions of data to sort through? then send 20-30 records?

Comment: @LeeDongyobEric the database will handle much quicker than javascript

Comment: @LeeDongyobEric but anyway, you can still do it on client side, make sure to use that library, it will help you a lot

Comment: Thanks you for your responses. I am asking question out of genuine curiosity and I have one more question. Why is database faster than javascript? Is SQL always faster in querying the data than the javascript? Rather than having 1000 request server to sort and filter, wouldn't there be advantage to have each individual local machine to handle sort and filter for the sizable amount of data?

Comment: @LeeDongyobEric just added some links that you can check